# How to change the property of an object inside an array propertly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
this.state = {
  myArray = [
    {
    name:"cat",
    expand:false
    }
  ]
}

clickItem(item){
 item.expand = true;
 this.setState({})
}

this.state.myArray.map((item) =>{
 return <div onClick={()=>this.clickItem(item)}>{item.name}</div>
})
```

In React, i have a simple array of objects,

when i click on one of theses object, i want to change their prop and update the state, what is the proper way of doing this.

i feel like there could be a better way

Comment: You are directly mutating the state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your state, update the copied state and the set the state.

```js
this.state = {
  myArray = [
    {
    name:"cat",
    expand:false
    }
  ]
}

clickItem(key){
 let items = this.state.myArray;
 items[key].expand = true;
 this.setState({items})
}

this.state.myArray.map((key, item) =>{
 return <div onClick={()=>this.clickItem(key)}>{item.name}</div>
})
```

Comment: `key` and `item` are the wrong way round in your `map` call. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map it's also worth noting that adding or removing items before or after will cause random elements to toggle state because you're using the index instead of data to address an `item`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a couple of things.

You're mutating the state directly which is going to fail silently and you're also missing the `key` prop on your `<div`.

This is easily resolved though by using the data you have available to you. I don't know whether each `name` is unique but you can use that as your `key`. This helps React decide which DOM elements to actually update when state changes.

To update your item in state, you need a way to find it within the state originally, so if `name` is unique, you can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to update it.

```
clickItem(item) {
  const targetIndex = this.state.items.find(stateItem => stateItem.name === item.name)

if (targetIndex === -1)
  // Handle not finding the element 

const target = this.state.items[targetIndex]

target.expand = !target.expand // Toggle instead of setting so double clicking works as expected.

this.setState({
  items: this.state.items.splice(targetIndex, 1, target) // This replaces 1 item in the target array with the new one.
})
}
```

This will update state and re-render your app. The code is untested but it should work.